# largest element all lists in Panda Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas series say

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 3, 334],
    [333, 4, 5, 3, 4]
])
```

I want to find the largest element in all lists, which is 334, what is the easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Only works if elements are actually `list`.  This is because `sum` concatenates lists.  This is also likely very slow.

```
max(a.sum())

334
```

---

**Option 2**
minimal two tiered application of `max`

```
max(map(max, a))

334
```

---

**Option 3**
Only works if all lists are same length

```
np.max(a.tolist())

334
```

---

**Option 4**
One application of `max` on an unwound generator

```
max(x for l in a for x in l)

334
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
max(max(i) for i in a)
```

Functional variant:

```
max(map(max, a))
```

Alternative method which only calculates one `max`:

```
from toolz import concat

max(concat(a))
```

For the fun of it below is some benchmarking. The lazy function `concat` and optimised `map` / list comprehension do best, then come `numpy` functions, `pandas` methods usually worse, clever `sum` applications last.

```
import numpy as np
from toolz import concat
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([list(np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)) for i in range(1000)])

# times in ms
5.92  max(concat(a))
6.29  max(map(max, a))
6.67  max(max(i) for i in a)
17.4  max(x for l in a for x in l)
19.2  np.max(a.tolist())
20.4  np.concatenate(a.values).max()
64.6  pd.DataFrame(a.values.tolist()).max().max()
373   np.max(a.apply(pd.Series).values)
672   max(sum(a,[]))
696   max(a.sum())
```

Comment: Thanks for the timing :-)

Comment: @Wen, no problem, nothing too surprising here, but always fun to see what works well. maybe i'll use `concat` more :).

Comment: Yep , will consider that too :-)

Answer (score 1):

To dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(a.values.tolist()).max().max()
Out[200]: 334
```

Or `numpy.concatenate`

```
np.concatenate(a.values).max()
Out[201]: 334
```

Or

```
max(sum(a,[]))
Out[205]: 334
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer using np.max:

```
import numpy as np
np.max(a.apply(pd.Series).values)
Out[175]: 334
```